# Closures and Interiors Sets Defined by Inequalities

Tags: general-topology, inequality

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3789484/computing-interior-exterior-and-boundary-points-of-a-set-a) question gave me the idea of asking a more general question—if a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined by inequalities, can we find the closure/interior simply by making the inequalities weak/strict respectively?
More exactly, let $F_1,\ldots,F_k$ be continuous functions $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$, let $c_1,\ldots,c_k\in\mathbb{R}$, and let $\mathcal{R}_1,\ldots,\mathcal{R}_k$ be either the symbol $\leq$ or $<$. Define
$$A := \left\{ (x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n ~\mid~ F_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)~\mathcal{R}_i~c_i,\text{ for } i=1,\ldots,k \right\}.$$
When is it true that
$$\overline{A} = \left\{ (x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n ~\mid~ F_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\leq c_i,\text{ for } i=1,\ldots,k \right\},\text{ and }$$
$$\mathrm{int}(A) = \left\{ (x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n ~\mid~ F_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)< c_i,\text{ for } i=1,\ldots,k \right\}?$$
I can see that it's not *always* true; for example, the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}~|~0<0\}=\varnothing$, whereas $\{x\in\mathbb{R}~|~0\leq0\}=\mathbb{R}$. Are all counterexamples of this kind, or are there more subtle counterexamples?

Comment: I think that this might be too general: mainly, I'm thinking aout the fact that a subset $A\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ is closed if and only if there is a $C^\infty$ function $F:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ such that $F(x)=0$ for all $x\in A$ and $F(x)>0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R^n\setminus A$.